# Docker Outside Of Docker login works but image pull from artifactory gives authentication is required error

Tags: docker, artifactory

In the docker host I create .docker/config.json with :

```
docker login https://project-docker.artifactory.company.com -u User -p Password
```

In the parent docker, then :

```
docker pull project-docker.artifactory.company.com/MyImage:1.0.0
```

works fine, the image is downloaded from the company artifactory register.

And I do :

```
docker rmi project-docker.artifactory.company.com/MyImage:1.0.0
```

to remove it from local repo.

Then I run a docker outside of docker with :

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock AnotherImage
```

Inside the child container (or sibbling), I do :

```
docker login https://project-docker.artifactory.company.com -u User -p Password
```

to create the /docker/config.json authentication file, it works fine.

Then when I do :

```
docker pull project-docker.artifactory.company.com/MyImage:1.0.0
```

I get the error message :

> Error response from daemon: Get https://project-docker.artifactory.company.com/v2/MyImage/manifests/1.0.0: unknown: Authentication is required

When I do :

```
curl -uUser:Password https://project-docker.artifactory.company.com/v2/MyImage/manifests/1.0.0
```

then curl manage to download that response.

So curl works from inside the container sibbling, but the docker deamon fails whith the docker pull made from the sibbling.

I know we use virtual sub repositories, because project-docker.artifactory.company.com points to the same IP as project2-docker.artifactory.company.com and docker.artifactory.company.com .

How I can have more precise info about where it goes wrong ?

Comment: In the low-level Docker API, [the client is responsible for sending registry authentication details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#section/Authentication); in the command sequence you show, the `docker pull` command has to find the credentials somewhere inside the container (the `docker login` isn't "sticking").  I'd start debugging around there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use `docker -D -l debug pull` to get debug but it's not showing anything. What do you mean by "not sticking" ? If the .docker/config.json is there what migth not be sticking ? I was thinking of maybe certificates that migth be present on the parent and not the child.